# A problem about Zariski topology

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Is $\mathbb{Z}$ a closed set or open set in $\mathbb{A}^1(\mathbb{C})$? This is considered under Zariski topology.

Answer (score 1):

The closed subsets of $\mathbb{A}^1(\mathbb{C})$ in the Zariski topology are exactly the finite sets and the whole space, since any non-zero polynomial has a finite number of zeroes. Hence, $\mathbb{Z}$ is not closed; it is not open neither, since it is not the complement of a finite set.

Comment: thank you very much. I thought that $\mathbb{A}^1(\mathbb{C})$ was different from $\mathbb{A}^1(\mathbb{R})$.

Comment: It is different (e.g. contains more elements), but the zariski topology comes in both cases from a PID and hence it is the cofinite topology.